# magento: Can't add products to cart - Primary key

Tags: php, magento, key, checkout, cart

So yesturday, my magento ishop broke down, i cant add any products to cart.

When i Click "Add to cart" it redirect me to cart and says:

" Cannot add the item to shopping cart. "

This is my log:

```
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'' in /var/www/clients/client23/web66/web/tests/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/clients/client23/web66/web/tests/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 /var/www/clients/client23/web66/web/tests/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array) #2 /var/www/clients/client23/web66/web/tests/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array) #3 /var/www/clients/client23/web66/web/tests/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array) #4 /var/www/clients/client23/web66/web/tests/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `sa...', Array) #5 /var/www/clients/client23/web66/web/tests/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `sa...', Array) #6 /var/www/clients/client23/web66/web/tests/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(574): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `sa...', Array) #7 /var/www/clients/client23/web66/web/tests/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(453): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->insert('sales_flat_quot...', Array) #8 /var/www/clients/client23/web66/web/tests/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(318): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->save(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote)) #9 /var/www/clients/client23/web66/web/tests/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php(1898): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save() #10 /var/www/clients/client23/web66/web/tests/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Cart.php(465): Mage_Sales_Model_Quote->save() #11 /var/www/clients/client23/web66/web/tests/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php(198): Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart->save() #12 /var/www/clients/client23/web66/web/tests/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Checkout_CartController->addAction() #13 /var/www/clients/client23/web66/web/tests/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('add') #14 /var/www/clients/client23/web66/web/tests/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http)) #15 /var/www/clients/client23/web66/web/tests/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch() #16 /var/www/clients/client23/web66/web/tests/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array) #17 /var/www/clients/client23/web66/web/tests/index.php(89): Mage::run('', 'store') #18 {main} Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'' in /var/www/clients/client23/web66/web/tests/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:234 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/clients/client23/web66/web/tests/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array) #1 /var/www/clients/client23/web66/web/tests/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array) #2 /var/www/clients/client23/web66/web/tests/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array) #3 /var/www/clients/client23/web66/web/tests/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `sa...', Array) #4 /var/www/clients/client23/web66/web/tests/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `sa...', Array) #5 /var/www/clients/client23/web66/web/tests/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(574): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `sa...', Array) #6 /var/www/clients/client23/web66/web/tests/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(453): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->insert('sales_flat_quot...', Array) #7 /var/www/clients/client23/web66/web/tests/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(318): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->save(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote)) #8 /var/www/clients/client23/web66/web/tests/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php(1898): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save() #9 /var/www/clients/client23/web66/web/tests/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Cart.php(465): Mage_Sales_Model_Quote->save() #10 /var/www/clients/client23/web66/web/tests/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php(198): Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart->save() #11 /var/www/clients/client23/web66/web/tests/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Checkout_CartController->addAction() #12 /var/www/clients/client23/web66/web/tests/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('add') #13 /var/www/clients/client23/web66/web/tests/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http)) #14 /var/www/clients/client23/web66/web/tests/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch() #15 /var/www/clients/client23/web66/web/tests/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array) #16 /var/www/clients/client23/web66/web/tests/index.php(89): Mage::run('', 'store') #17 {main}
```

I really hope, someone will come up with something.

( I dag google for a few hours, i found nothing. )

With regards,
iddi margšing

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this problem before. It has occurred when the database was being written to outside of the Magento API and something went wrong. An easy solution is to turn on the MySQL general log to record all sql queries. On the command line be looking at the mysql general log in realtime by using the tail program and the -f flag, like tail -f general.log

Now try to perform the action that's giving you the integrity constraint violation, you should see the attempted sql query in the log. With this info you should be able to better trace the problem and if needed, delete a bad entry in the database.

Sometimes It occurs due to extensions related to product also. In this case disable all 3rd party extensions and then try to add product.

Comment: Okey, i will try, Thanks for your replay!